# Understanding how to add data to a map with SFML functions

Tags: c++, dictionary, sfml

I'm doing this simple tutorial with SFML and c++ 11. I'm at the point where he teaches the map container. I have c# knowledge, and my understanding is map are the same as dictionaries. My question is about a code snippet he presents but doesn't explain well.

TextureHolder.h

```
std::map<std::string, sf::Texture> m_textures;
```

TextureHolder.cpp

```
sf::Texture& TextureHolder::GetTexture(std::string const& filename)
{
    auto& r_textures = m_s_instance -> m_textures;
    auto keyValuePair = r_textures.find(filename);

    if (keyValuePair != r_textures.end())
    {
        return keyValuePair->second;
    }
    else
    {
        auto& texture = r_textures[filename];
        texture.loadFromFile(filename);
        return texture;
    }
}
```

I understand everything except the else statement. This is my understanding of whats going on, but if anyone can clarify to me what is actually going on and why I'm mistaken, I would appreciate it.

`auto& texture = r_textures[filename]` This creates a new key value pair with the key of filename. It then assigns the value to texture, which is an empty value since no texture has been loaded.

`texture.loadFromFile(filename);` This loads a texture file and assigns it to texture. This is where i'm completely lost. Some way this line is also adding the texture to the value of the key.

Then it returns the texture to the calling function.

This is probably more of a misunderstanding of how SFML handles the texture object, but I'm still confused on how this line communicates with the key value pair in the map.

Comment: Note that this could have been written differently (and maybe it would be clearer) if the `map::insert()` were used instead of `[ ]`.

Comment: Well I've noticed he doesn't teach the best practices, but he's just trying to get you to understand the basic, without presenting to much information to you. I do plan to learn maps further in depth.

Comment: I posted an answer anyway, using `insert` that basically mimics your code.  You may find it useful (as others may also).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> auto& texture = r_textures[filename] This creates a new key value pair
>   with the key of filename. It then assigns the value to texture, which
>   is an empty value since no texture has been loaded.

Not entirely correct. `texture` is a reference. It's not a discreet object in of itself.

This creates a new key/value pair, and sets the reference `texture` to refer to the newly-created value, in the map.

The subsequent `loadFromFile()` invokes the `loadFromFile()` method via the `texture` reference. Which just happens to refer to the newly-inserted value in the map.

Then, a reference to the value, freshly loaded from the file, is returned.

The capsule summary: it searches the map to see if it finds the key, if it does it returns a reference to the key's value. Otherwise it creates a new key/value pair, for that key, initializes the new value, and returns it.

Comment: So my misunderstanding was more about how references work. This does give me more insight on references.

Answer (score 3):

> `auto& texture = r_textures[filename]` This creates a new key value pair with the key of filename. It then assigns the value to texture, which is an empty value since no texture has been loaded.

It doesn't assign the *value* to `texture`. It makes `texture` a reference to the newly-created texture. That's what the `&` in `auto&` does.

> `texture.loadFromFile(filename);` This loads a texture file and assigns it to texture. This is where i'm completely lost. Some way this line is also adding the texture to the value of the key.

It doesn't assign it to `texture`, it assigns it to the object that `texture` refers to -- remember, `texture` is a reference. It refers to the texture in the map.

> Then it returns the texture to the calling function.

Actually, it returns a reference to it. Remember, the return type was `sf::Texture&`.

Comment: I should've clarified. When I said value I was referring to it in the sense of <key, value>. So basically since texture is a reference to the "value", by adding the texture object to texture, you are actually assigning it to the <value>, and texture is acting like a bridge? I don't know if that makes sense.

Comment: The map contains a set of pair, each consisting of a key and a value. The call to `[]` on the map returns a reference to the newly-created value in the map.

Answer (score 2):

In this statement

```
auto& texture = r_textures[filename];
```

there is created a new pair in the map with key equal to `filename` and mapped value equal to the object created by calling the default constructor `sf::Texture()`. And the operator returns a reference to the created mapped value. This reference is stored in variable `texture` that is in turn a reference. So this reference refers to the original default-created object of the mapped type.

Then the original object of the mapped type that is stored in the map is updated

```
texture.loadFromFile(filename);
```

because variable `texture` is a reference to the object.

And at last this reference that is a reference to the original mapped object in the map is returned from the function

```
return texture;
```

Thus `operator []` either returns a reference to a mapped object if such an object that corresponds to the specified key is already exists in the map or creates a new mapped object calling its default constructor and also returns a reference to the newly created mapped object.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers explain the code that you posted.

However, as my comment suggested, usage of [std::map::insert()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) instead of `find()` and then `[]` may make the code clearer.  The trick is knowing what `std::map::insert` returns and how to use it.

```
sf::Texture& TextureHolder::GetTexture(std::string const& filename)
{
    auto& r_textures = m_s_instance -> m_textures;

    // potentially insert a new texture.  If not inserted, then the 
    // current one remains in the map
    auto ret = r_textures.insert(std::make_pair(filename, sf::Texture()));

    // ret is a std::pair<map::iterator, bool>, where map::iterator is 
    // the iterator to the existing or newly inserted item.  The second
    // is a bool that is either true or false, depending on whether new item
    // was inserted or not.

    // Now get the texture.  A map's iterator is itself a pair, so 
    // 'first' of this pair is the filename, and 'second' is the texture.
    auto& texture = ret.first->second;  

    // this tells us if it's a new item inserted
    if ( ret.second )  
       texture.loadFromFile(filename);

    return texture;   
}
```

This basically does the same thing as your version, only that it uses `map::insert` to determine if a new item has been inserted and uses the return value of `insert` going forward.

Note that `map::insert` takes a `std::pair` that consists of the "potential" new key and value (It is "potential", since we don't know if a new key will be inserted or not -- we make insert() decide that).

If the key already exists, then `insert` does nothing except to return the iterator/bool pair.  If the key didn't exist, then `insert` inserts a brand new `sf::Texture` by default constructing one (see the second parameter to the `make_pair`), and then the iterator/bool pair is returned.

Comment: I like it. Each step accomplishes more, and reduces the number of lines.